# Why do I get unexpected results when using a pipe and a herestring?

Tags: bash

When trying to both pipe the output of a command into another, and also have the second command read from a herestring, I do not get the results I expected.  For example:

```
echo "a" | grep -f - <<<abc
```

I would expect to produce the output

```
abc
```

but I get nothing instead

Answer (score 4):

Both the pipe and the herestring are trying to become `stdin` for the second command, here `grep`.  Using `strace` on it shows that only the herestring, in this case, is actually available to `grep`.  It then gets an empty "file" to search, and finds no matches.  Here is a portion of `strace` when the search space is a file instead of a herestring:

```
read(0, "a\n", 4096)    = 2
read(0, "", 4096)       = 0
<snip>
read(3, "abc\n", 32768) = 4
read(3, "", 32768)      = 0
```

but with the herestring we instead see:

```
read(0, "abc\n", 4096)  = 4
read(0, "", 4096)       = 0
<snip>
read(0, "", 32768)      = 0
```

so we never read the values from the pipe that we expected to have been our pattern space.

Using a process substitution does get around this problem, because then either the pattern space or the search space are not coming from file handle 0:

```
echo "a" | grep -f - <(echo "abc")
```

for example produces the exected `abc` output

Comment: Or even `grep -f <(echo a) <(echo abc)`.

Comment: or `grep -f - <<<"a" <(echo "abc")`